# RadListView - scroll to a specific y-position

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

In RadListView, is it possible to scroll to a specific y-position.

The problem is if I navigate to another page from a RadListView page and then come back - it initializes to the top of the listview. I would prefer to the same y position the user was at before navigating to another page.

I think there's a scroll-to-item method - but that's not necessarily the same y position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache your index using observable ViewModel and pass it when needed (in this case on the ***loaded*** event for your list - that is when the users will return back to the list page and the list will load)

e.g. TypeScript

page.ts

```
export function onListLoaded(args: RadListwModule.ListViewEventData) {
    list = <RadListwModule.RadListView>args.object;

    if (list.items) {
        list.scrollToIndex(roversViewModel.get("cachedIndex"));
    }

    list.refresh();
}

export function onItemTap(args: RadListwModule.ListViewEventData) {
    var tappedItemIndex = args.itemIndex;

    // "cache" the index of our tapped  item
    roversViewModel.set("cachedIndex", tappedItemIndex);

    // navigate to  details page or do what you want to do on itemTap
    frame.topmost().navigate(navEntry);
}
```

page.xml

```
 <lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" loaded="onListLoaded" itemTap="onItemTap">
```

Also give your cachedIndex [initial value of 0](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/models/rovers/rovers-view-model.ts#L29) for the first time the list is loaded.

Example based on [this POC app](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/tree/master/app/views/rovers) .
Note that is not exactly the same as scroll-to-the-exact-y-position but you can modify the logic and scroll further to the exact position with getting the cells relative position offset.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've found that the scrollToIndex() method makes the item visible - could be at the top, middle or bottom of the screen. So - how do I get the cell's relative position offset. There seems to be a scrollToPosition() method - maybe that's the solution?

Comment: Well at this very moment scrollPosition property is implemented only for iOS for RadListView http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/How-To/scroll-to-index#changing-the-position-of-the-scrolled-to-item-ios-only .. apart from that there is a pretty nice method called getLocationRelativeTo() that works on any View